# How do i upload data from my ios app into my sql database?

Tags: php, ios, sql, sql-server, json

Hi so for my dissertation I'm creating a sports analysis ios app with a website that compliments it. The app does many things but to keep it simple the coach selects the team, and tags any key events e.g tackle, pass etc. The application only shows stats on todays game, but on the website you can see stats from all the games.
However I need to find a way to upload those stats

I've found plenty of examples on how to get data from the external database using JSON.
However i cant find any example on how to upload data.

I'm using godaddy as my server which hosts my website and sql database.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are the examples getting data as json?

Comment: Ordinarily you would make an effort and when you run into a problem, post your code and ask a specific question. This sort of "how do I shot web?" approach is not likely to get you a helpful answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your server (php file) todo the Hard job
iOS side:
Use something like that to upload POST your values into the server (php file)

```
-(void)upload
{
    NSString *val1=@"";
    NSString *val2=@"";
    NSString *val3=@"";

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domain.com/file.php?value1=%@&value2=%@&value3=%@",val1, val2,val3];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *body= [NSMutableData data];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:nil];

}
```

Note: use this returnData if you need get something back after your uploading, like success message or some JSON (whatever you want).
Just Parse it to your needs.

On PHP file:

```
<?php

//GET the values from iOS.
$val1 = $_GET['value1'];
$val2 = $_GET['value2'];
$val3 = $_GET['value3'];



//connect to database
require 'connect.inc.php';

//just make INSERT SQL Request and done!.


?>
```

Hope It's Helping you.

Comment: Cheers for that! Thats helped a lot i'll crack on with this and if i run into any difficulties  i'll post my error. THANKS

Comment: @steff hi man, if my answer helped you, you can please vote up for the answer? thanks :)